# How to upgrade Apache 2 from 2.2 to 2.4 for Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, installation, apache-2.4

I was in the process of doing a test upgrade from Apache 2.2 to [2.4.3](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi). I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I would have upgraded to 12.04 for this to see if the upgrade would go a lot smoother. Unfortunately, I was told it wasn't an option...so I'm stuck using 10.04.

The process I did this was:

Before attempting this, I have managed to upgrade APR from 1.3 to 1.4  and APR-UTIL since apache has said they were prerequisites beforehand: http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi. I took the apr and apr-util and placed them under httpd-2.4.3/srclib

I have also taken Schlauberg's advise concerning libapr removal. So I removed all traces too when I removed all traces of the current apache.

First remove all traces of the current apache:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2
sudo apt-get remove apache2-common apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove

whereis apache2
sudo rm -Rf /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/include/apache2
```

Afterwards, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep apache2
```

Then install apache 2.4 with the following:

```
    wget http://www.bizdirusa.com/mirrors/apache//httpd/httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz   
tar -xzvf httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz   
cd        
wget     http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache//apr/apr-1.4.6.tar.gz   
tar -xzvf apr-1.4.6.tar.gz   
mv apr-1.4.6 apr   
cd   
wget     http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache//apr/apr-util-1.4.1.tar.gz   
tar -xzvf apr-util-1.4.1.tar.gz   
mv apr-util-1.4.1 apr-util
cd   
Place folders apr and     apr-util under /httpd-2.4.3/srclib
    sudo cp -r apr-util ~/httpd-2.4.3/srclib
    sudo cp -r apr ~/httpd-2.4.3/srclib    
cd   
download pcre-8.31.tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcre/files/pcre/8.31/   
    Please note that pcre-8.31 isn't obtainable through the wget but needs to be done     manually through sourceforge.             
tar -xzvf pcre-8.31.tar.gz && cd pcre-8.31   
sudo ./configure   
sudo make   
sudo make install   
cd   
cd httpd-2.4.3   
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all     --enable-deflate --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-proxy-http --with-mpm=prefork --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util   
sudo make   
sudo make install
```

After this process. I no longer get an error in installation. However, I think I'm missing a step because it's not found in /etc/apache2 and if I use a command that uses apache the terminal tells me it's not installed.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing after make install.

Thanks in advance for any help you have to offer!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have another libapr somewhere on your system. First I uninstalled libapr that came with the system, which caused a compile error.
Then I cleaned up everything except the source I found via

```
locate apr
```

Another make clean and make install fixed my problem